# Doctrine query to orderBy sum of users within the query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to perform a query on an entity of users who have completed a certain number of tasks each. There are different points values associated with each task and I need to create a query which will orderBy those with the most points from all of their tasks in the time periods shown below in the $timeArray.

I've already tried using a SUM query like so:

->select('SUM(t.points)')
->orderBy('t.points', 'DESC')

but this only gives an array of total points for everyone, I need to return an object that I can loop over and show users with the most points from all their tasks in the designated time period.

```
public function getTimePeriodUsers($userType = null)
{   
    $timeArray = [
        '-1 year', 
        '-3 month', 
        '-1 month', 
        '-1 week',
    ];
    foreach($timeArray as $time){
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $date->modify($time);
        if($userType == null){
              $resultsArray[$time] = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')

                    ->leftJoin('u.userTasks', 'ut')
                    ->leftJoin('ut.task', 't')
                    ->leftJoin('t.challenges', 'ch')     
                    ->andWhere('ut.completed > :date')
                    ->andWhere('u.enabled = :enabled')
                    ->setParameter('enabled', true)
                    ->setParameter('date', $date)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();


    }

    return  $resultsArray;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HIDDEN keyword. Basically you can declare a new field in the SELECT clause and mark it hidden to avoid the ORM fetching.

Simply add

```
->addSelect('SUM(t.points) as HIDDEN score') ->orderBy('score', 'DESC')
```

More reference in this articles [here](https://michelsalib.com/2012/03/04/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/) and [here](https://coderwall.com/p/o5snag/add-a-hidden-select-column-to-doctrine-query-builder)

Comment: Thanks Matteo, but this seems to return only one user whereas there are quite a few users with tasks in the time periods. Any idea why that is?